# Ubuntu upgrade failed

Tags: ubuntu, dual-boot, upgrade

I have a dual boot Ubuntu (12. something) and Windows 7 system. I upgraded to Ubuntu 14.something - on restart, Ubuntu offered me to upgrade to Ubuntu 16.something which I did as well but something failed during the upgrade.

Now, when I pick Ubuntu in the boot menu, it shows me a prompt where I can enter username, password and then see a shell. Before this I also see a message showing failure installing kernel modules.

In the boot menu, I see a Linux like partition name next to Windows - something of the format - `/dev/dm-0`. I do not see the Linux partition from inside Windows explorer.

I need to either reclaim the partition or re-install Ubuntu or any other Linux on it.

I cannot format the Windows partition as I have data on it.

Answer (score 0):

As you described, you have access to a shell prompt. From there you can try to reinstall the update. I'd try the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

It's possible that the update wasn't successful due to conflicts with packages. It would be very useful to know the error messages you received while upgrading.

If the above answer doesn't work, you can try reinstalling Ubuntu using a live USB installation.

Comment: Thanks Philippe. I tried the above - with update, it could not connect to the internet. Then one of the other two commands worked - don't remember which - by adding some flags like -f and --fix something and now I can see a GUI dialog. The dialog tells me that Ubuntu is running in a low graphics mode and I can either continue in low graphics or edit the config or exit - but after selecting one of the first 2 and clicking OK nothing happens.